# iOS handleOpenURL isn't called when becoming active??? iOS 5.1 (this is not a 3.2 issue)

Tags: ios, url, url-scheme

I use a URL scheme to open my app and parse the query string from the URL in `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  This works great, but it doesn't parse the new string when the app becomes active.  I have implemented the `-handleOpenURL:` and openURL methods as follows, but neither seems to be called when the app becomes active...

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (!url) 
        return NO;

    queryStrings = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (!url) 
        return NO;
    queryStrings = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    return YES;
}
```

Please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

The method you're using is deprecated.

Comment: @HackyStack Is the file copied despite the method not being called?

Comment: @HackyStack When you open a file from an app, for example to iBooks, iOS will copy the file to iBooks's Documents folder, then open iBooks and call it's application:openURL: method. Here, the URL will be the fileURL of the file, already in the app's Documents folder. Is the file copied to your Documents folder?

Comment: My app is launched from a webpage and is passed a query string.  The user is then sent back to the webpage and may launch my app again with a different query string, but when they do, the new string isn't showing.  I realized though that openURL IS being called.  The problem is that viewWillAppear is not called in my viewController when the app becomes active again (and this is where I use the query strings to fill ivars).  This is a view-based app template, and I don't really know how to access my view controller from my app delegate... yes I'm an iOS noob...

Comment: Ahhh, so the problem is solved! It DOES call openURL. So I suggest you close this question. But

Comment: We can chat about the viewWillAppear thing if you want.

Comment: Ops, you don't have rep to chat. So... It's a view based app, so one app controller and one view controller?

Comment: Yes, please look at my new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015567/how-do-i-access-my-viewcontroller-from-my-appdelegate-ios

Answer (score 0):

`handleOpenURL` is deprecated on iOS 5: you should be using `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` instead - have you got an `application:openURL` method in your app as well? If not, add one and see if it gets picked up.

Comment: I implemented openURL as well.  I've tried each individually and currently have both implemented and neither is being called when the app becomes active from background.  Only works on launch...

Comment: Yes its working only on launch the application... but not from the urlschema... anyhelp?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the above accepted answer. You probably want to use this (I was confused by the accepted answer as it only includes the function you need and not what you need to include inside the function):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

I personally came to this issue through the Ray Wenderlich tutorial. There are also some good tutorials using Parse which show how to integrate the two.

The full tutorial this leads up to and from this point can be found here: https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios

Hopefully this helps lessen confusion around this issue :)