# Allowing orientation in iphone only for one view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have been developing an app which requires orientation only for one view, for which I require a way to detect the current view in the appdelegate page

Can anyone please help and tell me how this is possible

Regards,

Neha

Comment: do you want to know that which is the current orientation....?

Comment: No, I dont want to know the current. I just wanted to know if it is possible to allow only one of the views in the app with landscape view and not allowing the others. Also i wanted to know if it is possible to find out which is the currently viewed view in appDelegate page.

Comment: Your primary question is a duplicate of the noted question; your secondary question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637709/get-the-current-displaying-uiviewcontroller-on-the-screen-in-appdelegate-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the app's supported orientations here:

[image: Device Orientations]

If you select only `Portrait` then you essentially lock your app in the Portrait mode

### EDIT:

---

If you want all your `viewController`s to be locked in `Portrait` mode but allow multiple orientations to a single/selected `viewController`(s) then you could implement this *quick fix*:

In the **`viewController`** that allows multiple orientations:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(YES)
                                              forKey:@"allowLandscape"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(NO)
                                              forKey:@"allowLandscape"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In your **`AppDelegate`**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    //default setting when app starts
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(NO)
                                              forKey:@"allowLandscape"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    //...
}

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"allowLandscape"] boolValue]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to allow orientation for all the views just one view

Comment: @NehaDangui : updated answer. hope it helps :)

Comment: Actually I want the opposite. i.e. Lock all the views to portrait except for one view which should be allowed to be viewed in landscape mode too. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @NehaDangui: same concept, just change a few things around. ... updated answer. glad to have helped :)