# How can I handle iOS push notification directly in my top view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

All notifications are handled in `AppDelegate`, but usually they are needed in top controller to perform some actions on current view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `UIVIewController` conformed to protocol `UIApplicationDelegate`. And then get access to the top view controller using code answered here: [Get the current displaying UIViewController on the screen in AppDelegate.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637709/get-the-current-displaying-uiviewcontroller-on-the-screen-in-appdelegate-m/28699092#28699092).

Let's say you need to get remote notification in your top `UIViewController`, then in `AppDelegate` you just write:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    (UIStoryboard.topViewController() as? UIApplicationDelegate)?.application?(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Why not post a notification from the `AppDelegate`? Shouldn't ViewControllers do their jobs and not be the app's logic?