# How to get current visible view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the currently displayed `ViewController` using the following:

```
let currentViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
```

This property gives me the `TabBarController`. The only property after `presentedViewController` is "`childViewControllers`".

How could I use this to attain the currently displayed `ViewController`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current displaying UIViewController on the screen in AppDelegate.m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637709/get-the-current-displaying-uiviewcontroller-on-the-screen-in-appdelegate-m)

Answer (score 0):

If it is TabBar based Application then to check which is currently selected `ViewController` depends on following condition :

1. First Track which tabbar is selected e.g :Condition to check which Tab Index is selected
2. Maintain NavigationController for each TabBar
3. Then Check navigationcontroller stack last index to match up the ViewController . ( which is chilviewcontroller you can say).

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the selected view controller from the `tabBarController`. An easy way to do so is with this extension.

Just take note that it will not update with the correct value until `viewDidAppear`. Checking the property prior to that will give you your previous screen.

```
import UIKit

extension UITabBarController {
    var displayedViewController: UIViewController? {
        return selectedViewController
    }
}
```