# How to open a specific ViewController When Click / Tap On Local Notification .when App is in Background , Suspended, Terminated Mode

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

In my case, I am using both the type of Notification Push as well as Local Notification. So, Push and Local Notification is Working Properly and I have implemented code for Tap/Click on Push Notifications to Launch specific ViewController it is also working Properly. But the problem is Coming when I Handle Local Notification Click/Tap App Goes Crash. So, please give me a Solution for Both click/tap Local and Push Notification.

My Code to handle Click on Push Notification when the app is in Inactive State in AppDelegate:- DidFinishLaunching

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {` // When the app launch after user tap on notification (originally was not running / not in background)
    if launchOptions != nil{
        let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]
        if userInfo != nil {
            // Perform action here
              let dict = userInfo as! NSDictionary
            if dict.value(forKey: "gcm.notification.subtitle1") != nil
            {
                let Status =   Global.getStringValue(dict.value(forKey: "gcm.notification.subtitle1") as AnyObject)
                JumpToDesiredViewController(status: Status)
            }
            else
            {
              // JumpToDesiredViewController(status: "ToDo")
            }`       
            return true
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849078/how-to-open-a-notification-view-controller-when-a-ios-push-notification-is-recei/55849255#55849255

Comment: No, Dud this is not useful for me.

Comment: Please help me.