# How to get an existing UIViewController (not rootviewcontroller) in AppDelegate.m?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, delegates

In my AppDelegate.m I want to get the UITableviewcontroller of the storyboard. The init view controller is a tab bar controller(is it the rootviewcontroller?), and I used

```
TableViewController*tmp = [rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlarmlistTableViewController"];
```

to get the controller. But it seems this TMP is not the existed controller that I want.
I just want to get the data of the tableviewcontroller and do something.

I searched the question but all I get are  "how to get a delegate method in a viewcontroller",opposite ones.

Comment: Check this answer:

*http://stackoverflow.com/a/29773513/4173671*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get an existing view controller out of the storyboard. Seeing that you seem to have a reference to the root view controller, you can find your table view controller among its children, with something like:

```
UITabBarViewController *tabBarViewController = (UITabBarViewController *)rootViewController;

UITableViewController *tableViewController;

for (UIViewController *viewController in tabBarViewController.viewControllers)
{
    // you can probably find a better way of identifying your table view controller

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class])
    {
        tableViewController = (UITableViewController *)viewController;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: THX! That's exactly the way I'm seeking for.

Comment: Help! I tried the code but "if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class])" never executes. I'm sure the rootUIViewController is tabBarViewController, and it connected to a navigationController, which is connnected to a TableViewController.

Comment: Well UINavigationController has a viewControllers property as well, so you could use something like the above to find your UINavigationController, and then search in its viewControllers for your UITableViewController. I admit that approach is super ugly though.

Comment: Yeah I made it, though kind of ugly... Maybe I will try some other ways like init the controller in AppDelegate.m. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from the tableViewController if it's hardcoded in the tableviewcontroller's .m you just need to instantiate the viewcontroller in your AppDelegate.m doesn't matter which instance it is at the moment. But if it's the dynamically generated data. You could pass the data through delegates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any other `UIViewController`, not just the `rootViewController`:

```
UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *root = [window rootViewController];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = root.storyboard;
CustomViewController *vcc =(CustomViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardID"];
```