# Call ViewController Method from AppDelegate after URL Scheme OpenURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to call a function `LoadWebpage` in ViewController.m from AppDelegate.m.

I have enabled my app with a URL Scheme such that "urlscheme://?querystring" links in Safari open my app.  I am capturing the url scheme in AppDelegate (I can tell by logging that this is working) and would like to fill a global variable with the querystring and then call my `LoadWebPage` method so that the view controller can use the global variable and open the requested website in a WebView control.

I am following [this tutorial](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/deep-linking).

This is is AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
    NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
    NSLog(@"URL query:%@", [url query]);
    URLString = (NSString *)[url query]; //extern variable

    [self.ViewController loadWebpage];
    return YES;

}
```

And in ViewController.m:

```
- (void)LoadWebpage{

    NSString *strURL=URLString;  //more logic will be required to get the appropriate url from the query string.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];

}
```

But the line `[self.ViewController loadWebpage];` has an error "Property 'ViewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'".

I'm guessing I need to synthesize a reference to the open viewcontroller, but I can't find info on how to do this.  Is this the best way to handle this?

Edit: Based on Yan's comment below, I tried to add

```
ViewController* mainController = (ViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;
[mainController LoadWebpage];
```

Instead of `[self.ViewController loadWebpage];` but it just ends debugging with lldb?

Comment: I think you meant write self.viewController    let me know if that works.

Comment: It does not work either way.  The auto complete has no "viewcontroller" with any capitalization, either.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015567/how-do-i-access-my-viewcontroller-from-my-appdelegate-ios  The answer shows how to access the root viewController

Comment: I tried to do that and then call the LoadWebpage function but it just ends debugging with lldb?  Sorry, I'm not very experienced with this and don't know what that means or how to get around it.

Comment: Update the answer with the exact error. Might able to see what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than trying to have the AppDelegate trigger something off in your View Controller, I would suggest having the View Controller register to receive a notification when the app starts.  You can then check the variable you're setting in AppDelegate and react accordingly.

For example:

YourViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This notification is sent the first time the app launches
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(applicationBecameActive:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object: nil];

    // This notification is sent when the app resumes from the background
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(applicationEnteredForeground:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object: nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was a much better solution than I was shooting for.

Comment: Before iOS 6 (?), you had to add the observer in viewWillAppear, and remove the observer in viewWillDisappear (in case the view was unloaded).  When openURL is called, the viewWillAppear is not called (this is the expected behaviour). Just wondering what the pattern would be back in the day when we had to remove the observer?

Answer (score 3):

For the ones, who have want it in Swift!

First, create NotificationCenter post method (In Swift 2.0 - NSNotification Center), where you want to send data:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NOTIFICATION_NAME"), object: nil)

    return true
}
```

In your ViewController class, where you want to receive the data, add the following in super.viewDidLoad():

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.YOUR_METHOD_NAME),
name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NOTIFICATION_NAME"),
object: nil)
```

And the method you want to call:

```
func YOUR_METHOD_NAME(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Your method calling, or what you want to do with received data
}
```