# How to get App delegate to display a specific UIViewController after PushNotification

Tags: uiviewcontroller, notifications, local, appdelegate

I have a TabBarController as the App entry point. After a receiving **Local-Notification**, I want to display a specific **UIViewController**.

Depending on the actual App-state (frontmost / not-frontmost, not running), I am able to catch the push notification by e.g. `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` in the appdelegate.

However, I am **not able to manage** to open a specific UIViewController at that point (that by the way is not one of the `tabbarcontroller.selectedIndexes`) .

I tried various things, e.g. `presentViewController`:

```
Today*today = [[Today alloc] init];
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:today animated:NO completion:nil];
```

leaving to **Error**:

`Warning: Attempt to present <Today: 0x7fcb91ed5a40> on <UITabBarController: 0x7fcb91c79810> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Posts here indicate to use `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` before calling `presentViewController`: **Same error**!

Further posts [ [thisOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) ] indicate that this error can be omitted by putting `presentViewController` in `viewDidAppear:` however, this is not possible in the appdelegate, where i catch the local notification...

Even calling a **segue** is not possible, as it seems that no View Controller has been loaded at this point already...

Some people indicating that calling a **UIViewController** from **AppDelegate** is not possible at all, is this right ?

I am out of ideas, do you have any how to do that.... ?!?

Comment: Check this answer:

*http://stackoverflow.com/a/29773513/4173671*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

Make sure that your UIViewController (here Today) is embedded in a NavigationController.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

Today* today=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Today"];

UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:today];
self.window.rootViewController =nil;
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any other `UIViewController`, not just the `rootViewController`:

```
UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *root = [window rootViewController];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = root.storyboard;
CustomViewController *vcc =(CustomViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardID"];
```