# How to open specific ViewController from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question has been asked many times. But I am a newbie and I was not able to find any solutions to help me in my condition. Here is a brief explanation:

I have an app with a UITabBarController as root.

Inside the app delegate I check if user is already logged in. If yes I will open root controller.

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

My application is working fine. But now I need to implement notification. When I get notification content inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
NSString *messageType = [notificationPayload objectForKey:@"messageType"];
```

Now if there is a message:

```
if (messageType.length > 0 )
{
    //Here based on message I need to open different tabs of TabBarViewController

     UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
     //RootTabBarViewController *listingVC = [[RootTabBarViewController alloc] init];
     [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

}
```

This piece of code above did not work for me.
And also I don't know how to open different tabs and give value to their badges form here. It always navigate to the first index tab with these code. I have seen other answers say:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

But did not work for me. I have implemented an `UITabBarController` class and I can set value for the each tab item badges from there but I get my `notificationPayLoad` in AppDelegate.

Comment: Try this and modify it to your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015567/how-do-i-access-my-viewcontroller-from-my-appdelegate-ios/29773513#29773513

Answer (score 0):

As you told that you are using TabBarController with storyboard. Then why are you initialising again? You can just do as following

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"Selected"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"Selected"];
        UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabController.selectedIndex=1;
    }else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"Selected"];
        UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabController.selectedIndex=0;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Here I am just showing a demo code for accessing TabbarController at different selectedIndex within didFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have designed(drag n dropped UITabBar/ UITabBarController) in storyboard.

```
if (messageType.length > 0 )
{
    //Here based on message I need to open different tabs of TabBarViewController



    NSUInteger indexOfRequiredTab = 2;// pass the index of controller here

    id rootObject = self.window.rootViewController;
    if ([rootObject isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {

        UITabBarController *tabBarControllerObject = (UITabBarController *)rootObject;

        if (indexOfRequiredTab != NSNotFound && indexOfRequiredTab < tabBarControllerObject.tabBar.items.count) {

            tabBarControllerObject.tabBar.items[indexOfRequiredTab].badgeValue = @"2"; //to set badge value

            tabBarControllerObject.selectedIndex = indexOfRequiredTab; //Setting this property changes the selected view controller to the one at the given index in the viewControllers array
        }
    }


}
```

Views designed on story board are already initialized, we can access them using the `IBOutlet` and change their properties.