# Is there a way to change a UIImageView's state from the App Delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, switch-statement

I have declared 4 images in the ViewDidLoad in my ViewController and then hide them with `myImage1.hidden = YES;`.

I was wondering if there was anyway of sending a message from the App Delegate (from within a Switch Case) to the ViewController's `ViewDidLoad` method, which sets the `UIImageView` to hidden: `myImage1.hidden = NO;`

```
-(void)playIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    switch (index)
    {
        case 1: 
            [self playOne]; 
            [// something here to tell the UIImageView .hidden = NO;]
            break;
```

I'm not sure this is possible but thought someone might be able to shed some light on what I'm trying to do. I really just want the image to become visible at the same time as the `case 1: [self playOne];` when it's called.

If not done this way, is there another other method I could try to achieve this?

```
`- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


UIImage *redSquare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_square.png"];
UIImage *blueSquare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_square.png"];
UIImage *greenSquare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_square.png"];
UIImage *yellowSquare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_square.png"];

UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(72, 117, 60, 60)];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(188, 117, 60, 60)];
UIImageView *imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(72, 254, 60, 60)];
UIImageView *imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(188, 254, 60, 60)];

[self.view addSubview:imageView1];
[self.view addSubview:imageView2];
[self.view addSubview:imageView3];
[self.view addSubview:imageView4];

imageView1.animationImages = @[redSquare];
imageView2.animationImages = @[blueSquare];
imageView3.animationImages = @[greenSquare];
imageView4.animationImages = @[yellowSquare];

imageView1.animationDuration = 1;
imageView2.animationDuration = 1;
imageView3.animationDuration = 1;
imageView4.animationDuration = 1;

imageView1.hidden = YES;
imageView2.hidden = YES;
imageView3.hidden = YES;
imageView4.hidden = YES;

[imageView1 startAnimating];
[imageView2 startAnimating];
[imageView3 startAnimating];
[imageView4 startAnimating];
```

The Switch statement in the app delegate is: (Including the ViewController reference)

```
-(void)playIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    ViewController* mainController = (ViewController*)         self.window.rootViewController;

switch (index)
{
    case 1: [self playOne]; [mainController imageView1Hidden]; break;
    case 2: [self playTwo]; break;
    case 3: [self playThree]; break;
    case 4: [self playFour]; break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by :

1. Property variable of that ViewController.
2. By firing local Notification

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, although you probably shouldn't include this logic in the app delegate (but I admit I'd need more context to direct you otherwise).

You can access your view controller from the app delegate. See the answer to this question on how to do that:

[How do I access my viewController from my appDelegate? iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015567/how-do-i-access-my-viewcontroller-from-my-appdelegate-ios)

Then, in your view controller you could have properties (of type BOOL) that specify whether the corresponding image views should be visible. Something like this in your view controller's .h file:

```
@property BOOL imageView1Hidden;
```

Then, in your switch statement you would set that property, and in the viewDidLoad method (of your view controller) you could check those properties to determine whether to set the hidden state for the image views.

Not entirely elegant, but it would work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The link to the page is helpful, however it does not state where to put the `MyViewController* mainController = (MyViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;` Am I to assume it goes inside my `-(void)playIndex:(NSInteger)index
{` ?

Comment: Sure. That's one place it could go. It can go wherever you need a reference to your view controller.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Will I need to `#import "ViewController.m"` ?

Comment: Yes, you will need an import. But just import the header:
#import "ViewController.h"

Comment: oh I see, no wonder I was getting the linker error!! In the `- (void)hideImageNO:(BOOL)imageView1Hidden
`, I can't seem to retrieve the variables from the `ViewDidAppear` (I switched from `ViewDidLoad`) Am I needing to declare something?

Comment: You'll probably need to post more code examples for me to be able to help further. I don't know which variables you're trying to access.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to sign that comment off with a thank you!

Comment: Yeah, so assuming you have a property in ViewController.h called imageView1Hidden (of type BOOL), you can do this in viewDidAppear:
imageView1.hidden = imageView1Hidden;

Comment: I've done as suggested but when I try and play the sequence, the programme terminates with `Thread 10: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: I populated my `imageView1Hidden` with 

`- (void)setImageView1Hidden:(BOOL)imageView1Hidden
{
    imageView1Hidden = _imageView1Hidden;
    
    UIImageView *imageView1;

    imageView1.hidden = NO;
}`