# Check Switch status from App Delegate in another View in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, switch-statement

I want to check the status of a Switch (is ON or OFF) in another UIView from App Delegate in Objective-C. This is my code but not working. I don't know if I have properly setup UIView header that i can reach the View from App Delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    PrivacyPolicy *privacyPolicy = [[PrivacyPolicy alloc]init];
    if ([[privacyPolicy switchAuto] isOn])
    {
        //do something
    }

    else
    {
        nil;
    }
```

I have found this code, but in Swift 3, can anybody please translate to Objective-C? I think that code is what I need.

```
if defaults.value(forKey: "switchON") != nil{
    let switchON: Bool = defaults.value(forKey: "switchON")  as! Bool
    if switchON == true{
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red()
    }
    else if switchON == false{
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green()
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to put it this way, but this is wrong on so many levels.

First of all, you are allocating and initializing a new PrivacyPolicy view, which does just that: it creates a new view (it CREATES it, but it does not SHOW it) and looks at the state of its switchAuto property, but it will always return the initialized state of that property, which I suppose is not what you need.

Secondly, you are doing that in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, which is fired just once on app launch. What are you trying to achieve, exactly, and when? Are you sure you should do that in AppDelegate?

Comment: The swift code you provide is probably used to *set* the value of a switch according to a value saved in the app's UserDefaults (I'll go on a limb here and suppose that "defaults" object is declared as *var defaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()*)

Comment: In your code, you are trying to access a switch that you just init. You might consider making PrivacyPolicy as a singleton. Or if PrivacyPolicy is a UIView you added on a ViewController, [try to access that ViewController first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015567/how-do-i-access-my-viewcontroller-from-my-appdelegate-ios).

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is for testing purposes i want put it in applicationWillEnterForeground, i have a function to check time (is day? or Night?) and then setup the app. All is working except that i cannot reach the switch from AppDelegate.

Comment: using didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not a good idea even if you want to use it for testing: as mentioned, it will be called only once, at startup, and never again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add a BOOL property in AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isPrivacyPolicyOn
```

and set it when the PrivacyPolicy's UISwitch changes value (you first have to connect the switch from Interface Builder to the PrivacyPolicy class):

```
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.isPrivacyPolicyOn = [self.switchAuto isOn];
}
```

(Remember to import AppDelegate.h in PrivacyPolicy)

This way, in whatever method you use in AppDelegate, you will just have to check for its isPrivacyPolicyOn value, not access a view's property (which is not a good idea whatsoever):

```
if (self.isPrivacyPolicyOn) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

---

A different approach: use NSUserDefaults, so that you keep completely untied AppDelegate and PrivacyPolicy (which is always a good thing).

In PrivacyPolicy's switch IBAction you set a value in the userdefaults:

```
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender {
    NSNumber *switchValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[self.privacySwitch isOn]];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:switchValue forKey:@"privacySwitch"];
}
```

And in your AppDelegate's whatever method:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *privacySwitchValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"privacySwitch"];
BOOL isPrivacyOn = [privacySwitchValue boolValue];
```

This way, the value set by the user will be non-volatile, and you'll be able to check it whenever you like. In this case, checking it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will work as expected.

Comment: please notice that I am assuming your code is just for toying around with UISwitches, BOOLs and an app going and coming from the background, because there are plenty of things that could go wrong in here (first of all, when the app is killed and relaunched, the value of that BOOL will be reinitialized - you should need to set a NSUserDefaults key to have it set in a non-volatile way)

Comment: Thank you so much, its working properly now! You helped me a lot!

Comment: Which solution did you implement?

Comment: The second one with NSUserDefaults, works perfect! Thanks again.

Comment: That's a way better solution, especially because there is no links between the two entities. AppDelegate should be as "agnostic" as possible regarding who is setting what, and when